# Bad memory alignment iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, rapidjson

I am stuck with the following crash report:

```
Date/Time:       2013-09-12 22:39:54 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xa0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39a3c564 _cache_getImp + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39a3e1d7 class_respondsToSelector + 31
2   CoreFoundation                      0x31b96605 objectIsKindOfClass + 37
3   CoreFoundation                      0x31b9635d __handleUncaughtException + 69
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39a41a65 _objc_terminate() + 129
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3948e07b safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3948e114 std::terminate() + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3948f599 __cxa_current_exception_type + 1
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39a419d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 13
9   CoreFoundation                      0x31adcf21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 457
10  CoreFoundation                      0x31adcd49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
11  GraphicsServices                    0x356a82eb GSEventRunModal + 75
12  UIKit                               0x339f2301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
13  Our App                             0x0003bc27 main (main.m:15)
```

After different attempts to fix the bug causing this error I keep receiving this crashlog again and again from PLCrashReporter (from our adhoc builds from the beta testers). The different exception codes vary from SIGSEGV/SEGV_ACCERR to SIGBUS/BUS_ADRALN to EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

I am using the [rapidjson library](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/) on iOS (armv7 and armv7s) with the padding fix as described [here (#8)](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/issues/detail?id=11) and I use the objective-c runtime functions to add method implementation on runtime (using `class_addMethod`).

Our codebase exists of mostly Objective-C code with some Obj-C++ and some C code. Memory Management is done by ARC except for the Obj-C++ and C parts which is handled manually. I looked into every malloc/free call and I extensively used libgmalloc to determine memory issues but there is nothing which does not seem correct to me.

I cannot reproduce this crashlogs myself, not in debug or release mode, but our beta testers keep sending me this crashlog once in a while (1 in about 50 runs). As our product (hopefully) will run on many iOS devices soon, this is not something we can left broken.

After reading a lot of memory management articles I suspect this issue is caused by bad memory alignment. Therefore I suspect rapidjson to be the cause of this bug. My lack of knowledge about memory alignment on iOS / armv7 does not allow me to fix this crashlog. Can someone explain me more about this subject on iOS? Or am I looking in the wrong place and is this another memory issue?
I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

If more info is needed I am happy to provide it. 
Note: I am not looking for answers as using JSONKit or another library to replace rapidjson. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was previously addressed here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/807860

In short, the original Objective-C exception has been released (eg, by an autorelease pool) prior to it being dereferenced in the uncaught exception handler. As such, __handleUncaughtException() dereferences a now-dead pointer, and you see the crash in your exception handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was indeed the cause. I was completely on the wrong track looking for the error. I am now able to reproduce this error in the debugger :)

Answer (score 1):

First, the address `0xa0000008` does not look misaligned, and `SEGV_ACCERR` does not mean an alignment problem, but a memory access permission problem (from sys/signal.h):

```
#define SEGV_ACCERR     2       /* [XSI] invalid permission for mapped object */
```

Considering you are using `class_addMethod()` and the crash is in `_cache_getImp()`, which is part of retrieving a method, my largely unfounded suspicion would be that you passed some invalid pointers to `class_addMethod()`, or overwrote that information later on.

Something to check would be whether you are using either globals or `malloc()`ed memory, because the runtime functions do not make copies for you.

Second, the crash you are seeing is secondary, you are crashing while running the top-level exception handler that is already terminating (`_objc_terminate()`) your program from an earlier exception, but in this case it's not a Unix signal, but an Objective-C exception:  `objc_exception_rethrow()`.

So you probably need to figure out that primary error first, for example from logs of the exception (just a backtrace isn't enough in many cases).

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I am gonna look into that. In the meantime, do you have any advice how to retrieve the exception logs? Should I use my own uncaughtException instead of PLCrashReporter? What properties of the NSException object should contain the needed information?

Comment: It looks like the secondary crash might actually be in PLCrashReporter.  Have you tried just removing it?

Comment: PLCrashReporter isn't visible in the given backtrace; this issue occurs prior to PLCrashReporter's involvement.